# Deciding a Canonical Question for R: How to load packages automatically/ by default?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

I suggest we need a canonical for this (it comes up all the time, let's merge the duplicates into it). Below are my suggestions on what are duplicates, and non-duplicates, and why; let me know what you think:

1. Suggested canonical [How to load packages in R automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300769/how-to-load-packages-in-r-automatically). This has three good answers and is already the most upvoted.
2. Duplicate: [R - how to “save” the loaded packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693812/r-how-to-save-the-loaded-packages)
3. The inverse of the question, which may also be a duplicate, in disguise, although this gets into locating multiple .Rprofile files [Make package in R not required to load when I startup R/RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167010/make-package-in-r-not-required-to-load)
4. Not exact duplicate: there are some nuances due to the way RStudio manages paths with whether/which .Rprofile is correctly picked up or not, see my answer [How to load packages automatically when opening a project in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238148/how-to-load-packages-automatically-when-opening-a-project-in-rstudio)
5. Not a duplicate: there can be issues with loading a package which has been installed, specifically due to Windows permissions used when installing [Packages won't run after installing in Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299545/packages-wont-run-after-installing-in-rstudio). And there can be other non-platform reasons, or just install hiccups, as the OP found.
6. and a near-duplicate, but just to show that the symptom keywords can be completely different: [r - object not found in script, but found in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858797/r-object-not-found-in-script-but-found-in-console) . (This was the question today which motivated me to find a canonical).

Comment: I actually spent a lot of time on this, so if you downvote or think the suggestion can be improved, just say how.

Comment: I'm willing to bet people read a bit too quickly and reacted to the title, but you could do with making a strong case on which question you think should be canonical and why.

Comment: @Makoto: I don't see that there's anything to "react to". I identified that this is something that comes up frequently and needs a canonical - doesn't seem controversial to me. Isn't it explicitly clear that I'm suggesting #1?. But since users here seem to love to quibble anything, they can propose their own, or disagree with the premise. In general, is it better to discuss canonicals by making the suggestion, or starting a discussion? No matter what I write on Meta and how much research work I put into something, people seem to love raining snark and being unconstructive. www.sigh.com

Comment: I can't read minds, so I can't understand what a downvote *means* on this one without having suggested something different. This post seems as uncontroversial and straightforward as it gets.

Comment: I would recommend not worrying about a handful of downvotes on Meta, especially if your question score remains net-positive. Those who disagree for a good reason will typically say so. The rest are usually just party poopers.

Comment: I'm trying to do my best being a party pooper @TylerH. I am!

Comment: Also note that the question in question will be better received as a canonical if it is turned into a community wiki. This will help avoid any aspersions that this effort is just a coordinated rep grab.

Comment: @TylerH: sad to hear. No good deed goes unpunished... there are tons such of confusingly-named R questions. (Ditto, aliases for files or executables)

Answer (score 6):

I agree that [How to load packages in R automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300769/how-to-load-packages-in-r-automatically) should be considered a canonical. The question is pretty clear, and the answer is highly upvoted and clear.

I think the other questions you identified as non-duplicates are correctly identified. They could possibly benefit from a separate canonical question.